# jquery get parent id not children

Tags: jquery

I have this html code :

```
<div id="main-link-1" class="menu-option">
  <div id="icon" class="menu-icon"></div>
  <div class="menu-text"> Overview </div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
```

I just want to add jquery click event to parent .menu-option and get the id "#main-link-1" :

```
$('.menu-option').click($.proxy(this.navigatorLink,this));
```

And the navigatorLink function :

```
navigatorLink : function(event){
    if(event.preventDefault) 
        event.preventDefault();
    else 
        event.returnValue = false;


    var link = event.target;

    var linkId = $(link).attr('id');
}
```

The linkId should be always the parent id : "main-link-1"

But when I click over the children, I get the children id. How can I get only the parent_id event when I click hover the children?

I know it should be easy, but I don't find the way without changing the html,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are looking for the `.parent()` function

Comment: What do you mean by "click hover"?...

Comment: Well, it all comes down to what's in that `'...'`.  From the sound of it, you're using a `this` improperly inside it.  Tell us what your actual `click` function is, and we can help you debug it. *EDIT* Actually, it sounds like you're using `event.target` when you should be using `this`.  See: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing#this-and-event-target

Comment: That really helps... I'm using event.target because I'm using an internal funciton. I'm going to edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the actual code in your question.  That makes it a lot easier to answer.

The immediate issue is that by using proxy, you lose track of the default `this` parameter, and that's what you need to use to see the element that's getting the call.  In using `event.target`, you get the exact element that is clicked on, not the element that catches the event propagation.  (See http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing#this-and-event-target for a nice visual example of the difference between `this` and `event.target`.)

I guess the question is: why are you using `proxy`?  It seems unnecessary, since you don't ever use `this` inside the function.  Unless there's more to your code than that, I would do the following:

```
$('.menu-option').click(this.navigatorLink);


navigatorLink : function(event){
    if(event.preventDefault) 
        event.preventDefault();
    else 
        event.returnValue = false;

    var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

If you do have code that uses `this`, so you can't make the change that way, you can keep your old code and make use of `closest`:

```
navigatorLink : function(event){
    if(event.preventDefault) 
        event.preventDefault();
    else 
        event.returnValue = false;

    var link = event.target;

    var linkId = $(link).closest(".menu-option").attr('id');
}
```